# Horizontal menu with dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, html-select, navbar

I'm trying to have a horizontal menu of items that all have dropdowns, but keeps going vertical and I cannot seem to figure out why.  the a tags are always taking up with full width of my page which is 900px.  But there is no style that is defining that.  So I'm lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have a screenshot or link? This is hard to diagnose by looking at code alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u using bootstrap 3, is it so, this code will work, see the working **[fiddle](http://bootply.com/81029)**,

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header"></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>

            <ul
            class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Web development</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a>
                </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>

        <ul
        class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Web development</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>

        <ul
        class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Web development</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Starting a Business</a>

        <ul
        class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Web development</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```